# GridView lost search result after change page size or click on paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview to show the data and and text box to do the search. When i search, the gridview could show the data correctly, but when I click on change page size or go to next page, the gridview will reload to the original state. Is there anything to do with the ViewState? Appreciate is someone could help. following is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

    protected void ddPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // handle event                 
        DropDownList ddpagesize = sender as DropDownList;
        GridView1.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddpagesize.SelectedItem.Text);
        ViewState["PageSize"] = ddpagesize.SelectedItem.Text;             
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "" + txtSearchValue.Text + "'";                   
        GridView1.DataBind();            

    }

    protected void btnReload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtSearchValue.Text = "";
        lblSearchError.Text = "";
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                row.Attributes["onmouseover"] =
                   "this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#AED4EB';";
                row.Attributes["onmouseout"] =
                   "this.style.textDecoration='none';this.style.background='#ffffff';";
                // Set the last parameter to True 
                // to register for event validation. 
                row.Attributes["onclick"] =
                 Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1,
                    "Select$" + row.DataItemIndex, true);
            }
        }
        base.Render(writer);
    }

    protected void btnDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "";
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int rowindex = GridView1.SelectedIndex % GridView1.PageSize;
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowindex];
            Session["TSO"] = row.Cells[7].Text.Trim();
            string url = "http://localhost:60918/Requests.aspx";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
            sb.AppendLine("window.open('" + url + "')");
            sb.AppendLine("<" + "/script>");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(upGrdCustomers, upGrdCustomers.GetType(), "myjs", sb.ToString(), false);
        }
        catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
        {
            throw;
        }                  

    }
```

Here is my code for the GridView:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:GridView runat=server></{0}:GridView>")]

public class GridView : System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView, IPageableItemContainer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// TotalRowCountAvailable event key
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly object EventTotalRowCountAvailable = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataSource"></param>
    /// <param name="dataBinding"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override int CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
    {
        int rows = base.CreateChildControls(dataSource, dataBinding);

        //  if the paging feature is enabled, determine
        //  the total number of rows in the datasource
        if (this.AllowPaging)
        {
            //  if we are databinding, use the number of rows that were created,
            //  otherwise cast the datasource to an Collection and use that as the count
            int totalRowCount = dataBinding ? rows : ((ICollection)dataSource).Count;

            //  raise the row count available event
            IPageableItemContainer pageableItemContainer = this as IPageableItemContainer;
            this.OnTotalRowCountAvailable(
                new PageEventArgs(
                    pageableItemContainer.StartRowIndex,
                    pageableItemContainer.MaximumRows,
                    totalRowCount
                )
            );

            //  make sure the top and bottom pager rows are not visible
            if (this.TopPagerRow != null)
            {
                this.TopPagerRow.Visible = false;
            }


        }

        return rows;
    }

    #region IPageableItemContainer Interface

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startRowIndex"></param>
    /// <param name="maximumRows"></param>
    /// <param name="databind"></param>
    void IPageableItemContainer.SetPageProperties(
        int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, bool databind)
    {
        int newPageIndex = (startRowIndex / maximumRows);
        this.PageSize = maximumRows;

        if (this.PageIndex != newPageIndex)
        {
            bool isCanceled = false;
            if (databind)
            {
                //  create the event args and raise the event
                GridViewPageEventArgs args = new GridViewPageEventArgs(newPageIndex);
                this.OnPageIndexChanging(args);

                isCanceled = args.Cancel;
                newPageIndex = args.NewPageIndex;
            }

            //  if the event wasn't cancelled
            //  go ahead and change the paging values
            if (!isCanceled)
            {
                this.PageIndex = newPageIndex;

                if (databind)
                {
                    this.OnPageIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }

            if (databind)
            {
                this.RequiresDataBinding = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    int IPageableItemContainer.StartRowIndex
    {
        get { return this.PageSize * this.PageIndex; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    int IPageableItemContainer.MaximumRows
    {
        get { return this.PageSize; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    event EventHandler<PageEventArgs> IPageableItemContainer.TotalRowCountAvailable
    {
        add { base.Events.AddHandler(GridView.EventTotalRowCountAvailable, value); }
        remove { base.Events.RemoveHandler(GridView.EventTotalRowCountAvailable, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected virtual void OnTotalRowCountAvailable(PageEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<PageEventArgs> handler = (EventHandler<PageEventArgs>)base.Events[GridView.EventTotalRowCountAvailable];
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

}

Comment: can you show us the code for gridview's markup? I don't see any code where you're rebinding the grid when you change the pagesize.

Comment: 1. Did you enable paging to your gridview? 2. You need to set GridView.PageIndex

Comment: I don't think he is using pagination for this but I think he controls the number of records to be displayed in the gridview through `ddpagesize` dropdownlist.

Comment: @DennisR, I just post the GridView code. Please take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably store the value of txtSearchValue.Text in SessionState (or ViewState) depends on page PostBack or reload. Regards,

Comment: It seems like you have posted code from `.aspx.designer.cs`, it's not going to help me. I was asking for code from `.aspx` for the gridview definition.

Answer (score 1):

In your server side event handler called ddPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged you are calling Databind on your grid without checking if there is a search term entered and setting that on the DataSource of the Grid.

protected void ddPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
   ...

SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "" + txtSearchValue.Text + "'";

GridView1.DataBind();

}

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It solved part of the problem, but when I try to click on the header of each column to sort the table, it will reload again, and ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. When you change the `pagesize` it triggers a postback and leaving the value for `SelectCommand` as empty resulting the gridview to load in it's original state. Set it to `txtSearchValue.Text` and try

```
protected void ddPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // handle event                 
    DropDownList ddpagesize = sender as DropDownList;
    GridView1.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddpagesize.SelectedItem.Text);
    ViewState["PageSize"] = ddpagesize.SelectedItem.Text;    
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "" + txtSearchValue.Text + "'";          
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It solved part of the problem, but when I try to click on the header of each column to sort the table, it will reload again, and ideas?

Comment: What's the event it fires up in code behind when you click on the header of each column (what's the sorting method you have written)?

Comment: I just used "Enable Sorting" in the Grid View Control

Comment: I think I got it. I just add "OnSorting" in the gridview control and do the same thing to the code behind. Thanks.